# Expand two views against each other inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have two views inside my coordinator layout, basically an image view and nestedScrollView (as Bottom sheet behaviour).

When the bottom sheet is sliding up and down, the image should resize accordingly, but at the moment it's not and I'm not sure why. How can I get the image to resize properly?

- This is my example layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CFCACA"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cartoon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_volume_up_24"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
                    android:background="@drawable/img_button_shape"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_volume_up_24"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="355dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curvy_layout"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_bg"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/verticalView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- This is my code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.verticalView);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.img);
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

        mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(layout.getMinimumHeight());

        tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        
        // Setting up recycler view

        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,4);
        assert recyclerView != null;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        bottomSheet.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        getTabsList();
        // Setting Up TabLayout
        assert tabLayout != null;
        createTabLayout(tabLayout,recyclerView);


    }
```